# Error when deploying my contract and interact with him

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js, ganache, error

Here is the error message :

```
Deploying, please wait...
BaseContract {
  target: '0x80f4D1df2Da11Ca9437A01519d3972d07E54A43E',
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [
      [ConstructorFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment]
    ],
    deploy: ConstructorFragment {
      type: 'constructor',
      inputs: [],
      payable: false,
      gas: null
    },
    fallback: null,
    receive: false
  },
  runner: Wallet {
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    address: '0x54749f5B877355917E1B862c49F3E9Ddb1cBD161'
  },
  filters: {},
  fallback: null,
  [Symbol(_ethersInternal_contract)]: {}
}
Current money in my wallet: 0
Adding money in my wallet ...
Current money in my wallet: 10
Taking money in my wallet ...
/Users/axelm/Documents/wallet/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129
            error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32000, "message": "the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 4 tx has nonce of: 3", "stack": "Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 4 tx has nonce of: 3\n    at TransactionPool.prepareTransaction (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:122021)" }, payload={ "id": 30, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction", "params": [ "0x02f89082053903843b9aca008483b5cc008271b49480f4d1df2da11ca9437a01519d3972d07e54a43e80a44fd9efc40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008c080a039fc3526c5dcda687379bc899275ebeca441585c265176647b8d543fa26ddbf0a06acfca03fe54ad066d724514d5604ccd79245db4a6f932493c6b1c60f623610c" ] }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.8.0)
    at makeError (/Users/axelm/Documents/wallet/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (/Users/axelm/Documents/wallet/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:653:41)
    at /Users/axelm/Documents/wallet/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:268:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
  error: {
    message: "the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 4 tx has nonce of: 3",
    stack: "Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 4 tx has nonce of: 3\n" +
      '    at TransactionPool.prepareTransaction (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:122021)',
    code: -32000
  },
  payload: {
    method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
    params: [
      '0x02f89082053903843b9aca008483b5cc008271b49480f4d1df2da11ca9437a01519d3972d07e54a43e80a44fd9efc40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008c080a039fc3526c5dcda687379bc899275ebeca441585c265176647b8d543fa26ddbf0a06acfca03fe54ad066d724514d5604ccd79245db4a6f932493c6b1c60f623610c'
    ],
    id: 30,
    jsonrpc: '2.0'
  },
  shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'
}
```

Node.js v18.18.1

---

Here is my JS file :

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
    const provider =  new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"); //connect to the blockchain
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("0x74ceb5628edb7b7041079783416727af07236f2708bbdf08bb56fd9991775914", provider);

    //get the abi and the binary
    const abi = fs.readFileSync("./wallet_sol_wallet.abi", "utf8");
    const binary = fs.readFileSync("./wallet_sol_wallet.bin", "utf8");
    
    //object use to deploy contract
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi,binary,wallet);
    console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
    //deploy the contract
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); // await for wait until the contract is totally deploy
    console.log(contract);

    let currentWallet = await contract.watch();
    console.log(`Current money in my wallet: ${currentWallet}`);
    console.log("Adding money in my wallet ...");
    let transactionResponse = await contract.store(10);
    currentWallet = await contract.watch();
    console.log(`Current money in my wallet: ${currentWallet}`);
    console.log("Taking money in my wallet ...");
    await contract.take(8);
    console.log(`Current money in my wallet: ${currentWallet}`);
   
    

}
main()
```

---

Here is my smart contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity "0.8.7";

contract wallet {
    uint256 private money;
    address private owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Error it is not your wallet");
        _;
    }

    function store(uint256 _money) public onlyOwner {
        money = _money;
    }

    function take(uint256 takenMoney) public onlyOwner {
        require(
            takenMoney <= money,
            "Error you don't have enough money in your wallet"
        );
        money = money - takenMoney;
    }

    function watch() public view onlyOwner returns (uint256 _money) {
        _money = money;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to add a small time delay for the nonce transaction counter to update.
Or you can use the next script

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
    const provider =  new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"); //connect to the blockchain
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("0x74ceb5628edb7b7041079783416727af07236f2708bbdf08bb56fd9991775914", provider);

    //get the abi and the binary
    const abi = fs.readFileSync("./wallet_sol_wallet.abi", "utf8");
    const binary = fs.readFileSync("./wallet_sol_wallet.bin", "utf8");
    
    //object use to deploy contract
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi,binary,wallet);
    console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
    //deploy the contract
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); // await for wait until the contract is totally deploy
    console.log(contract);

    let pending_nonce = await wallet.getNonce(); // for ethers version 6.2.+
    // let pending_nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet, 'pending'); //or this for ethers version 5.7
    let currentWallet = await contract.watch({nonce: pending_nonce});
    console.log(`Current money in my wallet: ${currentWallet}`);
    console.log("Adding money in my wallet ...");
    pending_nonce = await wallet.getNonce();
    let transactionResponse = await contract.store(10, {nonce: pending_nonce});
    pending_nonce = await wallet.getNonce();
    currentWallet = await contract.watch({nonce: pending_nonce});
    console.log(`Current money in my wallet: ${currentWallet}`);
    console.log("Taking money in my wallet ...");
    pending_nonce = await wallet.getNonce();
    await contract.take(8, {nonce: pending_nonce});
    console.log(`Current money in my wallet: ${currentWallet}`);
   
    

}
main()
```

Comment: Thank you its works now :))